# Can't connect to server using lftp

Tags: centos, ftp

I have a lftp file that I want to execute using the following command

```
lftp -f /usr/scripts/fileS.lftp
```

If I run this file I get `Delaying before reconnect:`

Now within this file (fileS.lftp) I have the following code

```
open -u username,password server
mput -E *
close
```

If I run `open -u username,password server` I get the following error `Couldnt get a file descriptor referring to the console`

I assume I need to allow a connection on the server I'm trying to connect to, how can I do this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this construct on a server:

```
(cat /root/1and1-ftp.txt ; echo "put $FNAME") | /usr/bin/lftp
```

Where `/root/1and1-ftp.txt` contains `open -u user,pass host`

I recall that I had some trouble getting `-f some-file` to work, so I'm doing this gross pipe thing.

Comment: Also, I'm doing "cat file" instead of "echo open (etc etc)" so that the password isn't visible on the command line.